# I want to upgrade postgresql from 13.4 to 13.11 version to clear vulnerability?

Tags: postgresql-13

there is a medium vulnerability on the vm and want to upgrade the minor version to the latest so the va will get cleared, and there is no internet on vm how i can upgrade the version from 13.4 to 13.11?